# Is the Atomic Wrangler necessary for The Courier Who Broke the Bank?

Tags: achievements, fallout-new-vegas

OK, I just got the Courier Who Broke the Bank achievement, having taken just a hair over 15,000 caps from the Ultra-Luxe. (I have a lot of patience, and like blackjack.)

Thing is, I'd already broken the bank at Atomic Wrangler. I didn't know whether or not it was necessary for the achievement, but since it had such a low limit (and a personal goal was to get banned from gambling at every casino), I took it down in between Gomorrah and Ultra-Luxe.

Was that necessary for the achievement, or just my own personal goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

The achievement is for getting kicked out of the three casinos on The Strip: The Tops, The Ultra-Luxe, and Gomorrah.

The Vicki and Vance, and the Atomic Wrangler do not count towards "The Courier Who Broke The Bank."

Comment: You can gamble at the Vicki and Vance? SWEET ... Another bank to break ... Because 50,000+ caps isn't enough. (At least not when repairs on some items run 10K!)

Comment: Yeah, go back 3 days after installing a new Sheriff.

Comment: SWEET! I'm going gambling tonight!